# Session not storing after header re-direct

Tags: php, session, twitter-oauth

I have a user system in which I store the users ID in `$_SESSION['uid']` and the user can browse around his account settings, However I recently added the ability to link your Twitter account...this is where it gets odd.

I have a twitter request page like so:

```
session_start();
require("twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php");  

// The TwitterOAuth instance  
$twitteroauth = new TwitterOAuth('***', '***');  
// Requesting authentication tokens, the parameter is the URL we will be redirected to  
$request_token = $twitteroauth->getRequestToken('http://livepierced.com/reg_twit.php');  

// Saving them into the session  
$_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $request_token['oauth_token'];  
$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];  

// If everything goes well..  
if($twitteroauth->http_code==200){  
    // Let's generate the URL and redirect  
    $url = $twitteroauth->getAuthorizeURL($request_token['oauth_token']); 
    //var_dump($url);
    header('Location: '. $url); 
} else { 
    // It's a bad idea to kill the script, but we've got to know when there's an error.  
    //die('Something wrong happened.');  
}
```

I can var dump the session at this point, and get the `UID`, `AuthToken`, and `AuthTokenSecret`

However once I have clicked Authorize on twitters side I am sent back to this page:

```
session_start();
require("twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php");  
if(!empty($_GET['oauth_verifier']) && !empty($_SESSION['oauth_token']) && !empty($_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'])){  
    // We've got everything we need  
    echo "<h1>TOKEN GOOD BRO!</h1>";

} else {  
    // Something's missing, go back to square 1  
    //var_dump($_REQUEST);
    //header('Location: req_twit.php');  
}
```

However, now my session has ether been destroyed, or has started a new session because var dumping the $_SESSION only gives me a session ID

Answer (score 0):

When the header redirect happens is it changing to a different url or sub-domain? For example do you start at mywebsite.com and end up at www.mywebsite.com?

I have never used the twitter api, but that is my first thought.